# Удаление записей из MySQL

Tags: сессия, cookie, php, mysql

Есть программа, которая проверяет наличие нужных записей в куках и если всё совпадает, то выводит нужную запись из БД в соответствии с id(который указали при вводе урл site.ru/del.php?id=[]). А если куки не подходят, то выводится ошибка.
На странице, рядом с данными из БД находится ссылка на удаление этих записей, после её нажатия обновляется страница и выводит ошибку, которая должна выводится при не правильном залогивании. 
Помогите пожалуйста

```
<?php
session_start();
$dblocation = "localhost";
$dbuser = "lol"; 
$dbpasswd = "0000";
$dbuser = "lol";

mysql_connect($dblocation, $dbuser, $dbpasswd) or die ("Не могу создать соединение");
mysql_select_db($dbuser) or die (mysql_error());
 $query = "SELECT * FROM cards where url = '".$_GET['id']."'";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_num_rows($res);
$res_1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cards` WHERE url = '".$_GET['id']."'");
while($row_1=mysql_fetch_array($res_1)){$url = $row_1['url']; $mail = $row_1['mail']; $pass = $row_1['password'];}
if($_SESSION['mail'] != $mail and md5($_SESSION['pass']) != $pass and $_SESSION['url'] != $url){die ('error-1');}

echo ("
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">

<head>

    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1251\" />

    <title>Вывод и удаление данных из MySQL</title>

<style type=\"text/css\">
<!--
body { font: 12px Georgia; color: #666666; }
h3 { font-size: 16px; text-align: center; }
table { width: 700px; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0px auto; background: #E6E6E6; }
td { padding: 3px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; }
.buttons { width: auto; border: double 1px #666666; background: #D6D6D6; }
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h3>Вывод и удаление ранее сохраненных данных из таблицы MySQL</h3>

<table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
 <tr style=\"border: solid 1px #000\">
  <td><b>Адрес</b></td>
  <td align=\"center\"><b>Имя</b></td>
  <td align=\"center\"><b>E-Mail</b></td>
  <td align=\"center\"><b>Skype</b></td>
  <td align=\"center\"><b>ICQ</b></td>
  <td align=\"center\"><b>Сайт</b></td>
  <td align=\"center\"><b>Телефон</b></td>
  <td align=\"center\"><b>Инфо</b></td>
  <td align=\"center\"><b>Удаление</b></td>
 </tr>
");

/* Цикл вывода данных из базы конкретных полей */
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['url']."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['mail']."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['skype']."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['icq']."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['murl']."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['phone']."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['info']."</td>\n";
    /* Генерируем ссылку для удаления поля */
```

$del = $query = "delete from cards where (url='$del')"; mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

```
    echo "<td><a name=\"del\" href=\"deleted.php?del=".$row["url"]."\">Удалить</a></td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo ("</table>\n");
mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: Это потому, что там фигня какая-то написана. И вообще каша полная. Этот скрипт надо просто выбросить. Его нельзя починить.

Comment: Зачем так сурово, человек учится. Очень легко послать нафиг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спокуха, Илюша! Сейчас поправим твой код. А те, кто говорят, "***...Этот скрипт надо просто выбросить***" они просто забыли, какими кодерами были в недавнем прошлом и их так же обламывали на подобных форумах. Итак, приступим. Илюха, выкладываю ТВОЙ КОД, с небольшими исправлениями и комментариями:

```
<?php

session_start();

$dblocation = "localhost";
$dbuser = "lol"; 
$dbpasswd = "0000";
//$dbuser = "lol"; // $dbuser уже определена, а вот указать БД не мешало бы
$dbdb = "lol"; // здесь и указываем БД

mysql_connect($dblocation, $dbuser, $dbpasswd) or die ("Не могу создать соединение");
//mysql_select_db($dbuser) or die (mysql_error()); // если имя БД = имени пользователя, то можно оставить эту строку
mysql_select_db($dbdb) or die (mysql_error()); // а если имя БД все-таки отличается, то оставляем эту строчку

// если в строке браузера есть ?id=
if ( isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']) ) {

$query = "SELECT * FROM cards where url = '".$_GET['id']."'";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_num_rows($res);

// если $_GET['id'] есть в БД 
if ( $row > 0 ) {

    $res_1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cards` WHERE url = '".$_GET['id']."'");
    while($row_1=mysql_fetch_array($res_1)){$url = $row_1['url']; $mail = $row_1['mail']; $pass = $row_1['password'];}
    if($_SESSION['mail'] != $mail and md5($_SESSION['pass']) != $pass and $_SESSION['url'] != $url){die ('error-1');}

}
// \если $_GET['id'] есть в БД

}
// \если в строке браузера есть ?id=

// если нажали на ссылку Удалить, то удаляем запись из БД
if ( isset($_GET['del']) && !empty($_GET['del']) ) {
$query = "delete from cards where url='".$_GET['del']."'"; 
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
// \если нажали на ссылку Удалить, то удаляем запись из БД

echo ("
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">

<head>

    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1251\" />

    <title>Вывод и удаление данных из MySQL</title>

<style type=\"text/css\">
<!--
body { font: 12px Georgia; color: #666666; }
h3 { font-size: 16px; text-align: center; }
table { width: 700px; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0px auto; background: #E6E6E6; }
td { padding: 3px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; }
.buttons { width: auto; border: double 1px #666666; background: #D6D6D6; }
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h3>Вывод и удаление ранее сохраненных данных из таблицы MySQL</h3>

<table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
 <tr style=\"border: solid 1px #000\">
  <td><b>Адрес</b></td>
  <td align=\"center\"><b>Имя</b></td>
  <td align=\"center\"><b>E-Mail</b></td>
  <td align=\"center\"><b>Skype</b></td>
  <td align=\"center\"><b>ICQ</b></td>
  <td align=\"center\"><b>Сайт</b></td>
  <td align=\"center\"><b>Телефон</b></td>
  <td align=\"center\"><b>Инфо</b></td>
  <td align=\"center\"><b>Удаление</b></td>
 </tr>
");

/* Цикл вывода данных из базы конкретных полей */
// если в строке браузера есть ?id=
if ( isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']) ) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['url']."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['mail']."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['skype']."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['icq']."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['murl']."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['phone']."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['info']."</td>\n";
    /* Генерируем ссылку для удаления поля */
    echo "<td><a name=\"del\" href=\"?del=".$row["url"]."\">Удалить</a></td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
}
// \если в строке браузера есть ?id=
echo ("</table>\n");
mysql_close();

?>
```

Данный пример можно посмотреть здесь http://tex-spassk.ru/tmp/test.php и здесь http://tex-spassk.ru/tmp/test.php?id=1

Comment: Спасибо... я уже и забыл про эту тему... очень давно писал. Я уже сам во всём разобрался.